# FullCalendar weekly event limit

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to specify the maximum number of events to be displayed in the same *time* slots in the weekly view (timeGridWeek)? What I am looking for is a solution similar to [eventLimit](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit) and [eventLimitClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitClick); these specify the maximum number of events in a given *day*, and work perfectly fine for the monthly view.

Comment: No, there's no option for this. About the only control you've got over the display of events in the grid view is [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap) which probably won't help you. You could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to see if you can get your idea included in a future release. In the meantime you might be able to cobble something together using eventRender and checking each event against a list of previously processed events to see if there are any overlaps. But I suspect it would be a bit awkward to get right.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @ADyson, turns out there is already a feature request for this: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4827

Answer (score 0):

Following a reply by [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), it turns out that the week timeline view does not work with eventLimit yet, meaning that all events will be rendered in the allocated timeslot rather than having a typical '+n more'. However there is already a an [accepted feature request](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4827) for this.